# Pausing script to get button input

Tags: javascript, loops

I haven't been able to figure out how to pause this script (twice) to get results of button clicks. It is meant to display an array of questions and answers. Here is the code:

```
let counter = 0;
while (counter < 3) {
  counter++;
  var x = document.getElementById("divC");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
document.getElementById('divA').innerHTML = question[counter];
document.getElementById('divB').innerHTML = '<button id="myBtn">Show Answer</button>';
document.getElementById('myBtn').addEventListener("click", function (){
document.getElementById("divB").innerHTML = answer[counter];
  var x = document.getElementById("divC");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
})
document.getElementById('divC').innerHTML = '<button id="myBtn2">Continue</button>';
document.getElementById('myBtn2').addEventListener("click", function (){
document.getElementById("divC").innerHTML = "";
})
}
```

Everything works until I put it in a while loop. Then it just dashes though the code to the last array element. Thanks for any help you can offer an old man.

Comment: You can use the prompt function to pause execution and get user input but that's bad UX imo. You can instead restructure your code and use a variable which holds the current step number then change your display based on the step number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly, you want to collect user input after showing each question, right?

### Problem

JavaScript code can not be 'paused' and it don't need to, because it will lock the entire page, and you won't be able to push any button. And so while loop can't help you with this functionality.

### Actual answer

You need to extract lines, that change divs texts to some function and run the function on button click.

it should look something like this

```
// store links to your elements in constants first
const divC = document.getElementById("divC")
const divB = document.getElementById("divB")
const divA = document.getElementById("divA")
const myBtn = document.getElementById("myBtn")

// declare some function that will toggle answer visibility
const toggleAnswerVisibility = function () {<your code goes here>}
// declare some function that will render next answer
const renderNextAnswer = function() {<your code goes here>}

// add event listener to show-answer-button to toggle answer visibility
<show-button element>.addEventListener("click", toggleAnswerVisibility);
// add event listener to continue-button to render next answer
<continue-button element>.addEventListener("click", renderNextAnswer);
```

Here's the answer, but don't look here right off the bat, try to code something yourself and then check out the link
https://codesandbox.io/s/pausing-script-to-get-button-input-fnzcw

Comment: Also try to name things somewhat reasonable (example in the provided link), I spent quite a lot of time trying to understand what does `divA/B/C` and both buttons do.
And read about `let` and `const`, `var` is a little bit deprecated
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/

Comment: I understand how this works, and it is very helpful. Thank you. The only problem is how to end the script when it runs out of questions and answers. There will be 100 of them.

Comment: You can store all questions in array. Just check if your count reached array length, display some kind of message on the screen and hide all the buttons

Answer (score -1):

> I haven't been able to figure out how to pause this script

I believe you're looking for the [debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger). here's a [video showing how to use it](https://youtu.be/TtsvMRxmfGA?t=459)